# Binding a command in tmux without using the prefix key

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen, tmux

Is it possible to bind a tmux command to a key combination and use it directly without first pressing the prefix?

I find `C-b + n` too cumbersome to switch panes, so I was wondering whether I could bind `C-1` for example, to switch to pane #1.

Or perhaps there may be a way to make the shortcut in the terminal emulator to send `C-b + 1` when I press `C-1`?

Thanks!

Comment: I just use `set -g prefix C-a`.

Comment: Me too, I just put C-b on my question because that's the default.

Comment: Some terminals support key bindings, which can translate "C-1" to a sequence of characters "C-b","1", e.g. [alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty), [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/), [urxvt](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For your example, use:

```
bind-key -n C-1 select-pane -t 1
```

The `-n` argument is used to bind-key, it means no prefix.

Comment: Thanks! That almost gets it done, except it doesn't recognize numbers, it says `unknown key: C-1`. If I use a letter it works. Do you know how I can specify a number key?

Comment: @Ivan: The usual codes for Control keystrokes come from ASCII. ASCII does not define codes for C-1..C-9. The standard ASCII control characters are C-@, C-a..C-z, C-[, C-\, C-], C-^, C-_, and C-?. Most terminals just do not support distinct codes for most modified keystrokes (though many support some modifiers for arrow keys and functions keys). You are probably better off using `F1` in place of `C-1` (also note that the pane numbers start at 0, not 1: bind F1 to selecting pane 0, F2 to 1, etc.).

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify that -n is an alias for -T root and explained a bit about it and sourced the docs.

Answer (score 7):

I have a quibble with the accepted answer here.

According to `tmux(1)`, `-n is an alias for -T root`.  So including `-n` doesn't actually mean that there is "no prefix" as much as it means the command will be bound to the root table, which is "not recommended".

`tmux(1)`:

> The root table is used for keys pressed without the prefix key:
>   binding ‘c’ to new-window in the root table (not recommended) means  plain ‘c’ will create a new window

What this seems to be saying is that:

`bind -n c new-window`

Will create a new window when `c` is pressed, and indeed, it does.

The dry humor in the author's phrase "not recommended" is the fact that "c" will of course be pressed many times in the average tmux session, given that ["c" is the third-most frequent letter in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_the_first_letters_of_a_word_in_the_English_language).

For another example, here is fast tmux window switching (using PageUp/PageDown keys):

```
unbind NPage
unbind PPage
bind -n PPage previous-window
bind -n NPage next-window
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this, I was searching the `man tmux` page and wasn't finding it. Also, I read that as "not recommended" to bind 'c' to new-window, not an "in general it isn't recommended" just specific to that example.

Comment: I also updated the accepted answer to clarify what -n does.

Comment: And lastly, thanks, I still can't get the ctrl + Tab working but can for non-ctrl keys, like N etc. But your suggestion to use pgup/pgdn is working and is kinda faster, me thinks. I'm gonna try it out for a while.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `Alt+,` to move left a window and `Alt+.` to move right. The choice might not make sense to you at first glance, but those keys are also used for <>, I'm just too lazy to add shift in there as well.

```
# switch windows without prefix
bind -n M-, select-window -t -1
bind -n M-. select-window -t +1
```

Same goes for panes. I like to use `Alt+[` and `Alt+]`.

```
bind -n M-[ select-pane -t -1
bind -n M-] select-pane -t +1
```

Answer (score 0):

I use vim style pane selection in my .tmux.conf

```
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

See also

- [VIM and TMUX navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator)
- [Seamlessly navigate VIM and TMUX splits](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/seamlessly-navigate-vim-and-tmux-splits)

I copied the tmux side of the configuration from here:

- Smart pane switching with awareness of Vim splits https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator