# bind tmux prefix to OS X cmd key (or any other binding)

Tags: macos, keyboard, tmux

I'm used to iTerm2 (or Terminal.app for this case) on OS X. But I want to move to use tmux (or screen, but the problem is similar to both apps).

So my idea is to have a single iTerm tab with a tmux session opened with multiple tabs. To do the transition I have a basic feature I need to configure on tmux: switch the the tab 'n' by using cmd + n (like Firefox, Chrome, iTerm2 itself, etc)

However I can't find a way of mapping the cmd key on the mac keyboard. I first tried to implement cmd as a prefix key, with no success. I've tried setting

`set-option -g prefix M-a (hoping for Meta-a)`

`set-option -g prefix ^a (hoping for ^ to work)`

but nothing works. Is this possible? I don't really need to bind the prefix to cmd, but I want to be able to change tmux tabs with cmd+n.

Thank you

Comment: karabiner-elements has a specific binding for tmux https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#modifier-keys

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to invoke a sequence of keystrokes (first `Ctrl-b`, then *n* ranging from 0 to 9).

Your best bet is to use a keyboard shortcut utility such as [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) or [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to do this for you.

---

Using **Butler**:

Select *+ » Smart Item » Keystrokes*, configure the *hotkey* `Cmd-1`. Press `Ctrl-B`, then `1` for the *Keystrokes*. Configure it to be only valid in Terminal (or iTerm). It will warn you that other applications might not like it, but you know that already.

---

Using **Keyboard Maestro**:

Create a new group on the left that is only available in Terminal (or iTerm).

Add a new item, triggered by *Hot Key Trigger* (`Cmd-1`) and add two *Keystrokes* to its actions: `Ctrl-B` and `1`.

---

You might also want to take a look at [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/238545/binding-a-command-in-tmux-without-using-the-prefix-key) -- doesn't use `Command` though, and didn't work for me using Terminal.

---

From the [tmux documentation](http://cheasy.org/tmux.pdf):

> Bind key key to command. Keys may be specified prefixed with ‘C-’ or ‘ˆ’ for ctrl keys, or ‘M-’ for alt (meta) keys. The −r flag indicates this key may repeat, see the repeat-time option.

They don't support a third modifier key.

Comment: omg what an awesome hack! it works too! used Keyboard Maestro because Butler seems overkill. Thank you!

Comment: Keyboard Maestro works wonderfully for this

Answer (score 29):

In iTerm2, you can map shortcuts to hex codes that get sent into the terminal.
Goto iTerm2 Preferences -> Keys.
In Global Shortcut Keys, click the + and add type your desired shortcut like the cmd+1, which will be captured. Then select "Send Hex Code". In the box that appears, type the hex codes that you want sent to tmux separated by spaces. Ctrl-B is 0x02, so for "Ctrl-B 1", type "0x02 0x31". See here for more hex codes: http://www.nthelp.com/ascii.htm

I mapped Cmd with h,j,k,l for moving around between tmux panes, and Cmd with % and " for creating the splits.
I'll probably do something similar to move between vim splits with one control key.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer for those using iTerm2. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working on my iTerm2 build 3.0.2

Comment: If this is not working it may be because iTerm2 binds the cmd key to switch-tab by default. Your modifier may be clashing. I had to change the swith tab key to option to get this to work on CMD+n

Comment: The link from the answer doesn't work: http://www.nthelp.com/ascii.htm. Does anyone have a substitute?

Comment: https://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/scen103/ascii.html

Comment: This is the right answer. It's a bit cumbersome as you need to map all the wanted keys, but works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Special shortcuts can be made with Terminal.app. I just found out the other day, but this may have been possible prior to lion.

Go into Preferences > Settings and click on the "Keyboard" tab. Now you need to add a new keyboard shortcut by clicking on the plus icon below the box. Now you want to set a key combo that "Sends string to shell."

Example:
Let's say I want to set M-LeftArrow to be mapped to `prefix-p` (previous window).

```
Key: Left Arrow 
Modifier: Option 
Action: send string to shell
```

Now just type in `prefix-p` into the input box where `prefix` is whatever you have set for tmux (I use cntrl-a so the box displays `\001p`). Note that if you make a mistake, delete characters will be inserted instead of actually deleting characters, so hit the "Delete one character" button to move backwards, in case you mess up.

Special characters I have set to make life easier:

```
M-Left  > Previous Window
M-Right > Next Window
M-Up    > Enter scrolling mode
M-Down  > Next Pane
```

You can also modify cntrl-anything and shift-anything, but do remember that these could interfere with your $EDITOR or other programs, so be careful about what special functions might be rendered useless.

Also, note that I could not figure out how to duplicate this functionality in iTerm2.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider the native (but very experimental) integration that iTerm2 offers with tmux:
http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/TmuxIntegration

That way, when you press Cmd-D to split the screen iTerm2 will split the tab for you. This is great, because the split is native, so you can drag the edge in the middle to re-adjust widths, or you can select a pane by clicking. Ditto for new tabs/windows (but the shortcuts are slightly different -- otherwise you'd have no way to add non-tmux tabs).

And like tmux, if you detach and re-attach, everything will be saved for you.

There are two caveats though:
* this is a very experimental feature and very flaky for me.
* you will have to build tmux yourself (using the archive somewhere on the link above).

-Chris

Comment: I know it's been two years, but any idea if this is still working? I followed the instructions at your link, but `cmd+D` splits iTerm2's panes, not tmux's.

Comment: @SamSelikoff You have to start it with `tmux -CC`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at this blog post that has very detailed explanations about tmux/iterm integration:
http://tangledhelix.com/blog/2012/04/28/iterm2-keymaps-for-tmux/

Comment: Web pages disappear and get moved all the time. Please at least summarize the contents of the blog post and give details of its title and author so that your answer doesn't become complelely worthless if the link breaks.